# Neo4j fulltext search. Don't score same word multiple times

Tags: database, neo4j, lucene, cypher

i have question about the neo4j fulltext search. I am currently working on a database with a lot of species names and i came across some behaviour i am trying to avoid.

Consider a fresh neo4j db with 3 nodes ([link to sandbox](https://sandbox.neo4j.com)).

```
CREATE (:Term {name: "(Arabidopsis thaliana x Arabidopsis arenosa) x Arabidopsis suecica"}),
(:Term {name: "Arabidopsis thaliana"}),
(:Term {name: "Arabidopsis thaliana x Arabidopsis arenosa"})
```

and one fulltext index

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX TermName IF NOT EXISTS
FOR (n:Term)
ON EACH [n.name]
```

If i now run the following search:

```
CALL db.index.fulltext.queryNodes("TermName","Arabidopsis")
YIELD node, score
RETURN score, node.name
```

You will find the following:

- 0.08451353758573532,    "(Arabidopsis thaliana x Arabidopsis arenosa) x Arabidopsis suecica"
- 0.0834571123123169,    "Arabidopsis thaliana x Arabidopsis arenosa"
- 0.08044059574604034,    "Arabidopsis thaliana"

So my query will return the complex `"(Arabidopsis thaliana x Arabidopsis arenosa) x Arabidopsis suecica"` first, because it contains the search phrase three times. Is there a way to tell the fulltext search query to ignore duplicate words? So that `"Arabidopsis thaliana"` would be scored highest because it contains the least amount of characters not contained in the search phrase?

Answer (score 1):

I cannot find a configuration in the fulltext query where you can ignore or filter the duplicated words in the index.

However, I have a suggested alternative solution for your question.  I will create a new property (call it name_clean_idx) which is a clone of name but the duplicated word(s) are removed.
The trick is to replace the first occurrence of the duplicated words by * then do a replace all then put back the first occurrence of the duplicated word.

An APOC function apoc.coll.duplicatesWithCount is used to find duplicated words in the name and split() function to create a list of word(s) in the name.

```
STEP1:

 CALL apoc.periodic.iterate(
   "MATCH (n:Term) RETURN n",
   "SET n.name_clean_idx = apoc.text.replace(n.name, '[^a-zA-Z ]', '')", 
   {batchSize:10000, parallel:true})

STEP2:

CALL apoc.periodic.iterate(
  "MATCH (n:Term) RETURN n",
  "WITH n, split(n.name_clean_idx, ' ') as coll
  WITH n as term, apoc.coll.duplicatesWithCount(coll) as dupArr  
  UNWIND dupArr as dup
  MATCH (term)
     SET term.name_clean_idx = replace(replace(substring(term.name_clean_idx,0, apoc.text.indexOf(term.name_clean_idx, dup.item)+size(dup.item)), dup.item, '*') + apoc.text.replace(substring(term.name_clean_idx, apoc.text.indexOf(term.name_clean_idx, dup.item)+size(dup.item)), dup.item, ''), '*', dup.item)",
   {batchSize:10000, parallel:true})
```

Then create the fulltext index on this new property;

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX TermName2  
FOR (n:Term)
ON EACH [n.name_clean_idx]
```

Thus, the new query will be based on a "cleaned" name (named clean for index):

```
CALL db.index.fulltext.queryNodes("TermName2","Arabidopsis")
YIELD node, score
RETURN score, node.name
╒════════════════════╤════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╕
│"score"             │"node.name"                                                         │
╞════════════════════╪════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│0.07456067204475403 │"Arabidopsis thaliana"                                              │
├────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│0.05851973593235016 │"Arabidopsis thaliana x Arabidopsis arenosa"                        │
├────────────────────┼────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│0.052836157381534576│"(Arabidopsis thaliana x Arabidopsis arenosa) x Arabidopsis suecica"│
└────────────────────┴────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Comment: Thanks for you quick answer! I have a few million terms in my database so i'll check if this solution is practical!

Comment: You can use apoc.periodic.iterate to do batch update on those million nodes. Thanks.

Comment: Please note that the frequency of the term in ALL the documents is taken into account during scoring, see here https://graphaware.com/neo4j/2019/01/11/neo4j-full-text-search-deep-dive.html